# Synchronisation of selenium PageFactory with test class fails

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I implemented a single PageFactory BasePage class that holds the weblements for a test page. I created a constructor in BasePage for WebDriver driver reference

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class BasePage {
  WebDriver driver;

public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {      //constructor
    this.driver = driver;
  }


@FindBy(xpath = "path")
public WebElement id;
@FindBy(xpath = "path")
public WebElement password;
@FindBy(xpath = "path")
public WebElement signIn;
```

I then initialised the BasePage class in inside the test class, this way: `BasePage basePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BasePage.class);`The initialisation throws no error.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Active {
public static WebDriver driver;
private final BaseUtil baseUtil = new BaseUtil();
BasePage basePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BasePage.class); //Initialisation


@Test
public void navigateToUrl() throws InterruptedException {
ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
driver = new ChromeDriver()
driver.get(baseUtil.getUrl());

basePage.id.click();
basePage.id.sendKeys("0000");
basePage.password.click();
basePage.password.sendKeys("admin");
basePage.signIn.click();

}
```

I ran the test, but it could not execute, throwing a NullpointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.click(Unknown Source)
    at Service.Active.navigateToUrl(Active.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Does anyone know what I have done wrong with the synchronisation of PageFactory with my test class?

Comment: Move the BasePage initialization inside the test method after driver is initialized. Basically the driver is null in the current code.

Comment: @Grasshopper, brilliant. Easy does it. It works. If you put the answer in an answer box, I can mark it as the official answer

Comment: @Grasshopper, with just a single method in the 'Active.java' class, the initialisation works great as you described. I have decided to add multiple methods, how can I make the driver global, instead of initialising every method? Currently, it can only be seen by one method. Adding the initialisation at the class level as I described in the codes above throws 'NullpointerException'

Comment: Use the BeforeClass method to initialize the driver. THen it will be available in all test methods. Also no need for making the driver static in Active class http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

Comment: Thanks. I replaced the Test annotation with BeforeClass and added the initialisation first at class level, got Nullpointer and then added the initialisation also to the BeforeClass method. Still got Nullpointer. Brower launched successfully, but no other method executed

Comment: Add the code to the question. Create a separate method and use BeforeClass annotation. Do not replace existing Test annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `BasePage` initialization inside the test method after driver is initialized. Basically the driver is null in the current code.